# Online receipt not being send to donors

Tags: email, contribution-page, receipts

we are creating two contribution pages for both new members and donnors and we are experiencing some problems with email receipts. We would be very grateful with any ideas on where to look or what to try next as we've ran out of them.

The issue is that receipts (emails) for donnors are not being sent when a donation is complete (new member emails are beign sent). We have checked the following:

- Send receipt is checked on Thanks and Receipt emails on the admin page for contribution
- It is not a problem of the payment processor (we've tried with 2 different ones, and the donation is marked as complete but the email is not beign send)
- The log says no email is beign sent. Meaning, is not a problem of the email getting lost on its way, but rather, that it is not sent at all.
- Email template is the default one.

Something odd is, new members who choose pay later get the New member email, where new members who use a payment processor get the Contribution mail.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you let us know what payment processor you've tried it with.

Comment: And you are certain that you have not customised any of the System Template Messages?

Comment: I used credit card (Sermepa, the Spanish most popular provider for online payments), and also Bank Account (SEPA, also used in the new members form, which does send confirmation emails) and also Pay Later option. None of them is even trying to send the emails.

As for the system templates, we did customize two of them, the one for new members and the one for new donations, but set them to default so we could see if the problem was in the changes we had made. :S

Answer (score 2):

You should check [CRM-15629](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629) and see if it sounds like the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the payment processor(s) are the issue. Unfortunately, the code on how to handle a successful payment was not really in a common place but duplicated, with potential differences (and bugs) into each of the payment processors.

The situation has improved, but it takes time to get all the payment processors using the new (common) features.

Could you test the following:
use paypal as the payment processor and make a simple contribution page (eg. with an amount of 0.10) and confirm that you receive the email.

As for the sepa I'm not that sure the payment should be considered as valid until we get the confirmation from the bank (5 days after you submit, that can be weeks after the donor filled the form), the payment is not really completed, so I don't find it that unexpected that the mail isn't sent