# Why aren't donation receipts being emailed to customer?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember, email, receipts

I'm having issues with emails being sent for new donations (membership signups actually).

I've tested each mail server type and I can send bulk emails, and test emails. 
I'm using PayPal as my processor and that seems to be working fine.

My contributions are being marked complete, and new contact/memberships are being created. It seems the only problem is the member isn't getting sent a receipt email.

I noticed this q: [Online receipt not being send to donors](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/777/online-receipt-not-being-send-to-donors/1997#1997)
which sounds similar but I think I've tested that it isn't a paypal problem.

When I tell the system to store the emails in the db, no email is being created, telling me the issue is within CiviCRM.

Any ideas?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a known, critical, and unresolved bug with WordPress and PayPal since 4.5.4. It has been reported as issue 16181, [Email reciepts for contributions being marked as sent but are not sending](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16181), and therein is noted as related or a duplicate to 15629, [Paypal IPN not working on Wordpress the first time](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629), which is also referenced in the other Civi.SE question.

Kurund suggests testing [patch 5647](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5647) to see if it resolves the problem.

---

**Update**: Both [Issue 15629](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629) and [Issue 16181](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16181) are marked as resolved as of 4.6.3.