# Troubleshoot Paypal Standard emails - Yes, tried patches (Urgent)

Tags: paypal, 4.6, ipn

Have event in in foreign currency and need PayPal Standard.

Running into a problem where emails are not being sent for event registration. 
Running 4.6.7 without enabling Invoices.

Paypal / Event email receipts work when using paypal pro or paypal express.

Using Paypal standard, IPN does seem to work properly as registrations are marked properly.

Reviewed many known issues like:

- [Why aren't donation receipts being emailed to customer?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/why-arent-donation-receipts-being-emailed-to-customer)
- Applied patch from https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17343 (added comment -
- Reviewed all jira entries for paypal + email in 4.x.x

NOTE: Logfile shows 2 IPN entries for each call:
[info] Contribution record updated successfully
[info] returning since contribution has already been handled

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you add a step-by-step scenario of what you are doing? And what you are expecting to happen vs what is actually happening. 

Also, if you are getting "[info] returning since contribution has already been handled" in the log file, I think it implies that this particular IPN call has already been handled by Civi.

Comment: Hi @BorislavZlatanov - don;t know what else to include.  I have IPN enabled on PP with default going to domain name (ie. https://example.org) .  I see the transaction log and shows the IPN notification with 200 status.  I see the data and email is correct.  URL is correct.  participant registration works.  just no email is triggered!

Comment: and email addres, event info, etc. are correct because it works if I use Paypal pro or express.

Comment: I actually spent some (too much) time looking at the PP transaction logs and system logs and cannot find an issue in the data.  I did see some retries which could account for the correct debug message.  Lot's of code logic to follow but unfortunately, we need to use PP standard for foreign currency events.  Can't see what part of code triggers the email receipt and why it would be skipped here and only with PP standard.